# Showing a Div Once per visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On my website I have a slider to only show on the Homepage. My home page looks something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="header"></div>
     <div class="slider"></div>
   <div class="maincontent"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

My Pages are the same layout, except I only want the Slider div to show on the first page. So when the user first arrives to the website, they can see the slider, but if they go to a different page, the slider is gone.

I was wondering if there was a way to do that with, jquery? Cookies? If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know how I would do this. Thanks!

Comment: Wait - do you want the slider to _only_ show on the home page, or on _any_ page but only on the first visit? The question can be read both ways.

Comment: If they go back to the home page do they see it again?

Comment: I suggest you add the slider div to the home page only using server side code. Why put it on every page if you're not using it?

Comment: What server framework are you using? Or is this only plain html files?

Comment: I'm using wordpress. I would like to add the slider to ONLY the first page that user see when they are on the website, besides the homepage.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. In fact, there are multiple ways. You can do it both using Javascript and a server-side scripting language like PHP. I recommend using a server-side scripting language, because there's no point in adding an element to a page if it isn't used, while it does take up a tiny amount of bandwidth. Anyways, an example using both methods follows:

Using PHP:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE['visisted'])) {
    setcookie('visited', true, time() + 3600 * 24); // Save a cookie for 1 day
    echo '<div class="slider"></div>';
}

?>
<div class="maincontent"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

And using Javascript:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#slider {
    /* Hide the div */
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="maincontent"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var cookie = document.cookie;
if (cookie.indexOf('visited=', 0) == -1) {
    var expiration = new Date();
    expiration.setDate(expiration.getDate()+1);
    document.cookie = 'visited=1;expires=' + expiration + ';path=/';

    var element = document.getElementById('slider');
    element.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</body>
```

By the way, I assume this isn't your whole HTML page? Because obviously you should add a doctype,  tags, etc.

Comment: How about once per visit, anywhere on the website, not just on the homepage?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Exactly the same. Just place the same code on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use:

1. Cookies, that can be accessed from js
2. HTML5 WebStorage, which is a great place too, but works only on new browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't bound to browsers I'd recommend to use the HTML5 LocalStorage variable.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

However if you are supposed to be browser independent (support IE6 etc.)
I would go with cookies or a database with visited IP's.